# Dynamic row creation in Excel using java

Tags: java, excel

I have to generate an excel from a resultset. Now, the result set returns one single row for one ID. I am using XSSFSheet createRow() and createCell() methods to create rows and columns from the resultSet. But now, I want to create the excel in the following format.

```
ID  |  Col1 |  Col2   |   Col3  |    Col4   | Col5   |
----|-------|---------|---------| ----------| ------ |
1   |   Dat1|  Dat2   |   Dat31 |      Dat41| Dat51  |
----|-------|---------|---------|-----------|--------|--
1   |    -  |     -   |   Dat32 |   Dat42   | Dat52  |
1   |    -  |     -   |    -    |   Dat43   | Dat53  |
1   |    -  |     -   |         |           | Dat54  |
```

---

Meaning, there will be multiple rows in the excel for the same Id, for some columns. The number of rows for that id will be the max of the number of rows of the Col3, Col4 and Col5. 
How do I create this in Excel using Java ?

Comment: Are you talking about cell regions? Maybe you will find a good use in `CellRangeAddress`

Comment: I have formatted the table in question. So, I think it will be more clear now.